# Difficulty in applying texture

Tags: rendering

I am trying to apply the brick texture on my house building but it is applying properly .
I am adding a picture for your reference.
Can anyone help? It would be great if yes. please help[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your texture is projected according to your UV (on the left). If you want it to be correctly projected, either create a seam before unwrapping (select a vertical edge and press *U > Mark Seam*) or unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* option:

[image]

Comment: thank you @moonboots